# Header only libraries with scons

Tags: c++, scons

I am new to scons so maybe my google-fu is really bad but I could not find a way to create a header-only C++ library. I know I can use `CPPPATH` to put directories in the include path but that is not ideal. My library `libonlyheader` depends on other external libraries like `fmt` and `boost` and I want executables and libraries built with these to transitively depend on `fmt` and `boost` as well. Essentially I am looking for a feature like the cmake's `INTERFACE` libraries.

Comment: What's wrong with using CPPPATH for this?  Might help to direct you if we knew the concern.

Comment: So if putting the headers in the include path is the only thing required to use the library CPPPATH is fine. An obvious problem arises when the header library depends on non-header libraries.

A more serious problem (from the newbie's perspective) arises when we have two  header libraries `liba` and `libb` that both contain a file `header.h`. What if within the same scons environment we want some targets to use `liba` and some to use `libb`? 

Unless I am missing something about how scons works, having a library not be represented as a library can bring some serious headaches.

Comment: Your collection of header files is not a "library" in the typical sense. A library produces a .a or a .so (or.dll),  This is more a package than a library.  If you need to include a library when you use your package, then you'll need to add that to LIBS where appropriate. You can add a method AddPackageXYZ which adds the include path and LIBS to your working Environment()...